# Different Scehma Databases Entity Framework Legacy System

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-schema

I have been building a new customization WPF Application for a legacy system. After a month, i was handed a larger database for testing, and i was surprised that the schema is different compared the last one given to me. My client then informed me that he has 100 of databases deployed at their clients, and each have slightly different schema.

I am using **Entity framework 6.1**, and it seems that it requires the same number of columns to be there in the table when that table process query. For Example:
my User table in the old database has (nullable) "ForgottenPass" field while in new database,it does not exist. The Entity framework throws an exception that column "ForgottenPass" is not found. I have 8 tables to work only, but there can be different number of columns on 100's of databases for these tables. The good thing is in those 8 tables, i have the fix number of columns to work with, but i have to perform CRUD operations on the table

Any help that how i can still be using EntityFramework for this will be a great help.

Comment: Do you need to care about the extra columns at all? And if the answer is yes, why? I mean, if you delete a row, does it matter what's in the columns? What if you update the fixed columns, do you need to update the extra ones? And if you're inserting new rows, won't the default value for those extra columns take care of what should be there?

Comment: EF will not cause any errors if there are columns it doesn't know about but it will generate invalid SQL if there are columns missing  that it has mapped properties for. You would only be able to work with columns and tables that you can guarantee will be there.

Comment: Thanks make sense, for keeping only those columns which i need. But the **Problem** now is that there is a column "teamid" which is not null and also does not have any default value, it has different datatypes in the db's (Small Int and Int). Can i make my EF to ignore the **datatypes** and work ahead. The thing is i am not usng the column but i need to have it at my edmx as it's not null. I remember at ADO.Net we use to have enableConstraints=false, and it skips these schema matching, any way to skip the datatypes in EF?